# Why would Firebase validation emails not come through TO MY OWN DOMAIN?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Auth for my solutions.

I get validated users every day - it's working.

I just tried to create two new accounts, using dummy email addresses from my own domain (the domain set up to send Firebase validation emails) and I do not receive messages.

That is, I do not receive the typical validation email.

I manually sent a password reset from the Firebase console to both new accounts; one email showed up.

I'm guessing this is a config issue on my hosted server / domain...but I don't know where to start looking.

Again, there is no issue with validation emails going out successfully - just not to the domain used to send those emails!

Comment: So Firebase is configured to use your domain as the sending email address for emails and this is the same domain that doesn't receive these emails from Firebase? It's likely that your domain is discarding the messages because it believes they've been [spoofed](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing) as it knows they aren't internal. What infrastructure are you using for your domain's emails?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this question. Maybe 20% of these emails are getting through. I use Siteground for hosting and don’t deal much with email setup. I’ll pitch your spoofing idea to them...